# PHP pass array without selected index

Tags: php, arrays

how to slice an array to pass it to a function. I cannot use unset because I need that array further. I know I can copy whole array to variable, however it's quite big and don't thing it's efficient. My code:

```
$list = array(0=>2123, 2=>1231, 7=>123123,...);
unset($list[0]); //I can't do this because I still need whole $list
$seats = $allocatingClass->allocateSeats($seatsNumber, $list); //here I need to slice $key from $list and pass $list without reiterating
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to splice it? http://www.php.net/array_splice . Also, if you need to keep the index 0, just store it somewhere, like $tmp = $list[0]; . Then splice the array, do what you need and push back your temp variable into the array, rather than storing the entire array somewhere else :)

Comment: You should add that as an answer to the question.

Comment: I like to comment first, when I don't exactly understand where the problem is :P

Comment: @briosheje yep :) I know that I need slice or splice, but I wanted to ask experienced programmers how to do that. I have these problems: 1. big array and I don't want to copy it. 2. I don't know how to use splice to pass array (without selected key and with the same keys) as argument to function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to keep index 0, store it, rather than storing the entire array elsewhere:

```
$tmp = $list[0];
```

Then splice the array:

```
$list = array_splice($list,1,count($list));
```

Then pass it to your function:

```
$seats = $allocatingClass->allocateSeats($seatsNumber, $list);
```

Then, when you need it, put back the value to the array:

```
$list[] = $tmp;
```

---

Edit: if you actually need to put it exactly at index 0, then you may want to unset the index 0 of the array instead of splicing it. If you can, however, push it at the end of the array just follow what is written above.

To clearify, if you need to LATER push back the element to index 0, do

```
unset($list[0]);
```

instead of the splice...

And to put back the element, do:

```
$list[0] = $tmp;
```

Comment: additional question :) I need to ordered array by key before splice?

Comment: @user2972127: according to what you want to do you may want to order it. If you don't want to re-order it after splicing, just store the value, unset the index you want to unset and then push it back to the unsetted index :)

Comment: @user2972127: yep, sorry for being late for the editing, I was testing if all the things were working correctly :]

Comment: sorry, but I not experienced in PHP. From my point of view this is rather dirty to do $tmp. I thoought PHP can slice and return array :)

Answer (score 1):

However you do it, a copy will be made when passing the array (unless you pass it by reference).

either use splice. or create a copy and shift one value.

after sending the copy variable, you can unset it so it wont keeptaking its space.

Edit :

The above solution is also viable. Though I suggest you use:

```
$tmp = array_shift($arr);
doStuf($arr);
array_unshift($arr, $tmp);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree but 3 copies > 2 copies ;)

Comment: still the same, thought PHP can do it without $tmp like doStuf(array_slice_key($arr,0))